# Why find the slope other than finding min , max?

Tags: derivatives, slope

I am confused about the slope value.
Lets' say we have :

$f(x) = x^3,f(5)=125$

$f'(x)=3x^2,f'(5)=75$

so what they usually say in this situation is that if $x$ increases by $1$ then $y$ will increase by $75$.

So , slope = 75 at $x=5$ I don't quite grasp this value of 75.

The equation of this tangent is $y=75x +b$ and solving for $b$ will result $125=75x+b$ so $b=-250$ and our tangent equation at $x=5$ is $y=75x-250$.

I understand why I need slope only when we are trying to find where is $max$ or $min$ but what useful info gives me if I find slope at let's say $x=3, 5, 1, 6, 100 ...$ and so on ? just for fun ?

Comment: You know it's very important. Suppose, you have $x(t)$; your position as function of time. What $x'(t)$ gives you is the instantaneous velocity at every moment. This is just one example of how powerful this is.

Comment: Also derivatives can be used to give you an excellent linear approximation(in fact the best) for your function around a certain real number $a$: $$f(x)= f(a) +f'(a)(x-a)$$

Comment: There are a few things. One is just that you want to know what the rate of change of one quantity is with respect to another; for example, the rate of change of position with respect to time, or the rate of change of temperature with respect to the position along a heated rod. Another is for approximation: near a given point you can use the tangent line to approximate a function in a neighborhood of that point. The biggest one is solving differential equations (not necessarily by hand in closed form, but just in general). Differential equations are the bread and butter of applied math.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_calculus#Physics notes a few other uses that may be handy here.

Answer (score 2):

Your words: "So what they usually say in this situation is that if $x$ increases by $1$ then $y$ will increase by $75$."

"They" don't say that. What, however, is true is the following:

If $x=5$ then $y=5^3=125$. If $x$ is incremented by a "small" amount $\epsilon$, positive or negative, to $x+\epsilon$ then $y$ undergoes a change of approximately $75\epsilon$ and will be about $125+75\epsilon$.

In precise terms:
$$y_{\rm curve}(5+\epsilon)=(5+\epsilon)^3=125+75\epsilon+o(\epsilon)\qquad(\epsilon\to0)\ .$$
On the other hand, if you look at the *tangent* to the curve at $(5,125)$, a straight line, then you can say that
$$y_{\rm tang}(5+t)=125+75 t\qquad(-\infty<t<\infty)\ .$$

Comment: Hello Herr Blatter
I found the example from http://www.themathpage.com/acalc/derivative-2.htm#prob2
They say that per one unit x , y increases by 75 units

Did I interpret it wrong ?

Comment: @Oleg This is a somewhat confusing thing about our language. For illustration, consider a car going at 90 km/h. This does not mean that 1 hour later, the car will have traveled 90 km. It means that if the car's speed didn't change along the way, then 1 hour later, the car would have traveled 90 km. But typically it *does* change along the way.